# grub bootloader not being seen by system since updating ubuntu mate 21.04 to 21.10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, mate, 21.10

system drive is a 2nd hand sata ssd, a Crucial CT2000BX500 2TB BX500, which I have had running fine in this system for 2 years.
Windows 10 is installed on the first half of the ssd, and boots and runs just fine. The built in Windows tool Diskmgmt.msc reports that the ubuntu drive partitions are healthy, but what can Windows know about Ext4 partitions apart from diddly-squat?

I installed Ubuntu mate 20.04 LTS amd64 in April of last year on my HP ProDesk 400 G3 with 16g
GB DDR4 and an Intel i7 6700 cpu @ 3.4ghz, eventually upgrading to 21.04 via the Ubuntu software updater graphical tool in May this year, and then to 21.10 recently.

Should I write a Ubuntu USB stick and try reinstalling grub? Could it be a Windows update that has written over the bootloader, or is there a way to inspect the boot partition for Windows first, which I believe is where grub should be..? And, to re-write grub, should I use a 21.10 usb, or a 20.04 usb? or some tool like RIPLinux?

Comment: I left ubuntu mate running on the computer while I watched a film downstairs. After the film finished I came back up to fing the cpu fan blasting at full throttle, so switched the computer off - could a SSD chip failure cause the fan to lose it's PWM control line?

Comment: Do you have latest UEFI firmware & SSD firmware? HP is known to not have Ubuntu first in UEFI boot menu, unless you change it using UEFI settings (not UEFI boot menu). And Windows updates are known to turn fast start up back on, and then grub2's os-prober cannot see the Windows  install to add it to grub menu. Grub only boots working Windows.